# Extension of Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-acceleration

Consider about the sum of iid random variables
$$
X_t = \sum_{i=1}^{t}x_i
$$
$x_t$ are of zero mean and finite variance $\sigma^2$. Let $M,m>0$. 
By Chebyshev's inequality, it is easy to show that
$$
H_t(M)\equiv P(|X_t|>tm+M)<\frac{\sigma t}{(tm+M)^2}
$$
That is, $P_t(M)$ converges with the same pace as $1/t$.

Then I am interested in the probability of following event
$$
G_t(M) \equiv P((t+1)m+M \ge|X_t|>tm+M)
$$
which should be much smaller than $H_t(M)$ and converge faster. But how fast it can be? Especially, can we make
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} H_t(M)
$$
convergent?

Comment: I think it depends on the distribution of $x_t$.

Comment: @Henry zero mean. Sorry. $M$ and $m$ are two positive constants

Comment: @Henry got your point